# Transposing a matrix from a PDF stripper

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am reading the text from PDF file using PDFBOX. I am able to read properly using "Rectangle2D". But issue where results shows one by one. Instead i want show in Transpose view.

**Current view**

PO-00145678

Vendor : AQ-00067

Date...................................: 5/10/2021
Expected DeliveryDate...: 6/10/2021

**Expected results**
**In one line**
PO-00145678 Vendor : AQ-00067 Date...................................: 5/10/2021 Expected DeliveryDate...: 6/10/2021

**Code using**

```js
public class PDFBoxReadFromFile {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\ed\\Documents\\test2.pdf"))) {

      if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        Rectangle2D rect4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(210, 160, 230, 25);
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(55, 290, 225, 17);

        Rectangle2D rect2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(281, 255, 255, 20);
        Rectangle2D rect3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(2, 365, 660, 1900);
        stripper.addRegion("class2", rect1);
        stripper.addRegion("class3", rect2);
        stripper.addRegion("class4", rect3);
        stripper.addRegion("class5", rect4);
        PDPage firstPage = document.getPages().get(0);
        stripper.extractRegions(firstPage);
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class5"));
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class2"));
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class3"));
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class4"));

        File file = new File("C:/Users/ed/eclipse-workspace/pdfboxreadfromfile/file.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class5"));
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class2"));
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class3"));
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class4"));
        pw.close();

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
    }
  }
```

**Second type but no luck**

System.out.print(stripper.getTextForRegion ( "class5" ) + (stripper.getTextForRegion( "class2")));
**results**

[image]

It should be like PO-003334823 Vendor : WL-00051

Comment: You are outputting the texts for each region with a line break attached (as you are using `println`). If you want the result on a single line, you should stop adding those line breaks.

Comment: @mkl can you share any examples? something like this System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion( "class5", "class2")  ?

Comment: How about using `print` instead of `println` in your code?

Comment: tried print but same please see my questions... I have added the recent update

Comment: What's the difference between "PO-003334823 Vendor : WL-00051" and "PO-003334823 Vendor : WL-00051"?

Comment: I Mean the resutls shows one by one instead of appearing in single line. Updated again pls check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214613/discussion-between-leace-and-mkl).

Comment: How about simply removing \n and \r characters from the string?